# tcsh set raw string to variable

Tags: string, tcsh

I am wondering if there is a way to set a raw string to a variable. In particular, a string that contains meta characters. Say I want to store "test[2]" into a variable without escaping the square brackets as shown below.

```
#! /bin/tcsh
set my_string = "test[2]"
```

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `set my_string = '"test[2]"'` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set noglob` to prevent tcsh from expanding globbing characters such as `[`:

```
% set noglob
% set my_string = test[2]
% echo $my_string
test[2]
```

You can use `set glob` to enable it again.